# How to copy a geometry with Python OGR?

Tags: python, ogr

I want to copy a geometry with Python OGR within a loop:

I tried the following, but I get `ERROR 1: Empty geometries cannot be constructed`

```
import ogr
import copy

d = ogr.Open('sampleData.geojson')
l = d.GetLayer()

for f in l: 
     gCurrent = f.GetGeometryRef()
     gPrevious = copy.copy(gCurrent)
```

I know I can't just assign `gPrevious = gCurrent` since it only references the geometry. But why is it trying to construct an empty geometry?

Comment: why you want to use the module copy ?

Comment: No particular reason. What would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't expect OGR to be Pythonic. In fact, there is a large list of [gotchas documented](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas) to describe these. Essentially, all of the variables are references to objects described in C++, so they often don't make sense with workflows in Python. Modules like `copy` only work on Python objects, which is why your example doesn't work as expected. You need to keep references to the features and the geometries alive, not just the geometry, [otherwise it will crash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/123458/1872).

For example, here is something that will calculate the union of current and previous features, showing the area of all three geometries:

```
l = d.GetLayer()

fPrevious = None
for fid in range(l.GetFeatureCount()):
    fCurrent = l.GetFeature(fid)
    if fPrevious:
        gCurrent = fCurrent.GetGeometryRef()
        gPrevious = fPrevious.GetGeometryRef()
        # Do something with the two geometries
        gNew = gCurrent.Union(gPrevious)
        print("Areas: %d vs %d vs %d" % (gPrevious.GetArea(), gCurrent.GetArea(), gNew.GetArea()))
    fPrevious = fCurrent
```

But if, for example, outside the loop did `gNew = gCurrent.Union(gPrevious)` it will crash since the references to the features have changed.

Answer (score 1):

@[Mike T](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1872/mike-t)'s [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126318/123828) tells you about some of the caveats of using OGR, but it doesn't actually answer your main question: how can you generate a **copy** of an OGR geometry?

I'm not sure if this is the *best* way to do so, but here's a simple and generic solution:

```py
gPrevious = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(gCurrent.ExportToIsoWkb())
```

Now you don't have two references that just point to the same geometry in memory. Instead, you actually have two separate geometries.

Answer (score 1):

`Clone()` method seems to work properly:

```
gPrevious = gCurrent.Clone()
```