# QGIS crash when looping through features in network analysis (dijkstra)

Tags: pyqgis, network, dijkstra

My script to compute distance in my network works. Now I want to loop over all features of a point layer to produce multiple distance calculations.
Just iterating over the features work of course and prints all of them correctly. When I add the rest of the script QGIS shuts down immediately after the first iteration, but I am not able to recover an error message.

```
for f in points_layer.getFeatures():

points_to_tie = [QgsPoint(f['longitudeO'], f['latitudeOr']), QgsPoint(f['longitudeD'], f['latitudeDe'])]

#PROGRESS:
#count += 1
#print "calculating number %s" % count

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, points_to_tie)
graph = builder.graph()

startId = graph.findVertex(tiedPoints[0])
endId   = graph.findVertex(tiedPoints[-1])
(dtree, dcost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, startId, 0)
print "Travel time from %s to %s is %s hours" % (f['municipOri'], f['municipDes'], dcost[endId])
del graph 
del tiedPoints
del points_to_tie
del startId
del endId
del dtree
del dcost
```

I thought this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123458/qgis-crash-when-i-try-print-geometry) was a good hint, but it doesn't solve it when I delete everything at the end of the loop.
Is there an obvious mistake that I am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that I loaded the network layer **outside** of the loop, which is something that python doesn't like apparently (I still don't know why). The solution is to load everything within the loop; apart from the layer that you are iterating over of course.